# VIM find next matching line?

Tags: vim, match, shortcut

In VI, how do I jump to the next occurrence (if any) of the entire current line?

Like * does for words, but for the whole of the current line instead of just the current word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is acceptable for you.
You can leave cursor on that line you want to search, then press:

```
/<c-r>=getline('.')<cr>
```

or

```
Y/<c-r>"<BS><cr>
```

or

```
:let @/=getline('.')<cr>
```

The idea is same, copy the line to `/` search. however, this will **not** work for all cases, e.g. your line contains a "regex" :

```
aaa.*foo (cursor here)
aaabbfoo
aaa.*foo
```

vim will match all three lines.

**Note** that you may want to wrap the line text with `^` and `$` to get better result.

Comment: that's cool.  And I can assign it to a short cut key easily enough, I guess.

Comment: So `nmap <D-8> /<C-R>=getline('.')<CR><CR>` seems to work fine.  Why do I need 2 <CR>s though I wonder?

Comment: @Thruston one to end the `<C-R>` and one to end the `/`

Answer (score 1):

there's no predefined command for this but you can do something like that:

```
:map <F7> 0v$hy/\V<C-R>"<CR>
```

The first part of the command copy the whole line into the default register, and the second part performs a search for it.
Then, just press F7 in normal mode, and that's all folks.

Another one i love:

```
:map µ yiw:vim /<bslash><lt><C-R>"<bslash>>/ *<CR>
```

It extends the search made with '*' for all files in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified version of Kent's answer that should always work and won't be confused by special symbols. (ie the sting is matched literally with nothing interpreted as regex)

```
/\V\^<c-r>=escape(getline('.'), '\')<cr>\$
```

The `\V` turns on very nomagic means that the only special character is the backslash. We use the escape function to escape all the backslashes (Thanks to Ingo Karkat)

Or in a mapping

```
:nnoremap <silent> ,* /\V\^<c-r>=escape(getline('.'), '\')<cr>\$<cr>
```

Comment: You can use the built-in `escape(getline('.'), '\')` instead of `substitute()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins that extend the `*` command to work on the selection in visual mode; one of them is my [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320). (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)

With that, a search for the current line is a quick `V*` (go to linewise visual mode, search for selection).